# Need help finding out why my program isnt doing what i want it to do

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that only works on 1 persons pc per login via grabbing the users machine guid and comparing it to one I've already set as the only "allowed" guid.

I currently have my own in there for testing purposes, but no matter how I try to write this, it always allows me to log in and continue through the rest of the program without closing when I change the digits of my mguid.

Does anyone know why it's not closing when it finds that the users (my) hwid isn't the same as the authed hwid given in "std::string frenchhwid"?

```
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
    GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo);
    wstring hwidString = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid;
    string hwid(hwidString.begin(), hwidString.end());


    std::string user;
    std::string pass;
    std::string hwids;
    std::string frenchpass = "lol";
    std::string frenchhwid = "dd07cef3-4ef5-4141-a8fb-5115def1f6e2";
    std::vector<std::string> usernames{ "french" };
    
    
    if (frenchhwid.compare(hwid) == 0);
    if (frenchhwid != (hwid))
        system("exit");
       print("username: ");
       std::getline(std::cin, user);
       if (in_array(user, usernames)) {
           system("cls"); //sorry non-windows users
           if (user == "french") {
               print("password: ");
               std::getline(std::cin, pass);
               if (pass == frenchpass)
```

Comment: Have you tried some experiments? (1) what does `system("exit");` do by itself?

Comment: Your `if (frenchhwid != (hwid))` statement has no curly braces after, meaning the only thing that'll be executed if the statement returns true is the line immediately after, `system("exit");` - everything else after gets executed regardless. Unlike python, scope has to be set in C++ with curly braces, not just indentation.

Comment: Scope is not set by indentation in c++, it appears that in some cases you are forgetting that you need to use {} to introduce a scope. Also the semicolon at the end of this statement makes the conditional pointless: ` if (frenchhwid.compare(hwid) == 0);`  you do nothing different if the condition is true or false.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (frenchhwid != (hwid))
        system("exit");
```

When you use `system`, it launches a new process to run the command you specified. The `exit` command exits the process. So you launch a new process which exits itself. This has no effect on the running process that launched the process that exits.

The most common version of this mistake is using `system` to change the current working directory. That launches a new process that changes its own working directory and then terminates. That accomplishes nothing.

*Never* use `system` to do something that the running process should do. If you want the running process to exit, you can't use `system` to do it because that creates a new process. And, in general, try not to use `system` to do something that the running process easily can do. It adds external dependencies and risk.